# Server Error in '/' Application-->The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm working in ASP.NET and i used the following code in jquery.And it is showing me error"The server tag is not well formed".please help me out guys.My Jquery Code is

```
$('#add').click(function () {
                var txtcnt = $('splting').text().split(';');
                var table = $(this).closest('table');
                for (var i = 0; i < txtcnt.length - 1; i++) {
                    table.append("<tr><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"label\" runat=\"server\" value="+txtcnt[i].toString()+"/></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"currentName\" runat=\"server\" value="+txtcnt[i].toString()+" /> </td></tr>");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Its not possible add server side controls through JQuery. Instead of use html input elements.

Comment: any other way na @Selva

Comment: Why you need dynamic textboxes? Is there any specific Requirement for that?

Comment: yes na..In dynamic textboxes i have to place some values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` runs purely on the `client`, whereas `ASP.Net` server-side controls exist primarily on the `server`.

so you cannot add server side controls through `JQuery`

> I think the best thing is  Use ajax for all and forget about
>   serverside controls

Or you can use hidden field. Store the data into Hidden field then you can take it from server

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is not able to create server controls. You would have to create html. You would be far better off using static html in most cases, especially considering some users may not have JavaScript enabled. To create server controls dynamically you would have to do it in the code behind.

As the other answer suggests Ajax would be a very good choice